# How to read today's day in Blue Prism? Example MONDAY

Tags: blueprism

I would like to extract Date base on T-1 only for weekday which is Monday to Friday. Currently I have 2 separate bot running. First bot if today is Monday, it will capture last Friday's date. And second bot is for Tuesday-Friday.

How can I add calculation or decision, where If today=Monday then T-3 else T-1. I would like to maintain just 1 bot.

Any such calculation able to apply in blue prism?

Or any other suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built-in function called `FormatDate`.

The function accepts two parameters, first being the date you want to format and the second being the date format: `FormatDate("30 03 2020", "yyyy-MM-dd")` returns `2020-30-03`

You can use the format to return only the weekday, for example:

`FormatDate("30 032020", "ddd")` returns `Mon`

or

`FormatDate("30 032020", "dddd")` returns `Monday`

Comment: Thanks. Is working fine. But how can I format today's date instead of hard code it? I try this but is not working.

FormatDate(now(), "ddd")

Comment: Strange, it should be working. Make sure you use Now() with capital N, I believe the functions are case sensitive. You could also try Today().

Comment: Yes you are right, is case sensitive. is working fine now. Thanks.